# jquery formatCurrency plugin keypress event

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the plugin formatCurrency to make me change the numbers to currency.
and I have this code:

```
$(".SePresu").keypress(function(){
    $(".SePresu").formatCurrency();
});
```

I applied pugin all inputs with class "SePresu" and far so good, the only thing that when I enter data into the "input" only allows me to put the numbers so $ 8,344 an integer and 3 decimal places when I want to be filled according to what the user gets.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nbNjT/

as I do to work properly and not show only 1 whole and 3 decimal

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are formatting on keypress. So as soon as you type a digit, jQuery formats the text, which forces the next digit you type to appear at the end.

I suggest formatting on blur rather than keypress. This would allow the user to type the necessary digits, but still automatically format as soon as the focus leaves the input.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".SePresu").blur(function(){
        $(".SePresu").formatCurrency();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbNjT/1/

jQuery blur documentation: http://api.jquery.com/blur/